# Count making it return one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where I need to get all the users who liked the post and their username and other info.

I tried creating a join query like so

```
$sql = "SELECT U.id AS userid, U.name AS NAME, U.username AS username,
               U.verified AS verified, U.private AS private,
               COUNT(IFOLLOW.user_id) AS i_follow, 
               COUNT(FR.user_id) AS requested 
        FROM posts AS P 
        LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON L.post_id = :postid 
        LEFT JOIN users AS U ON U.id = L.user_id 
        LEFT JOIN followers AS IFOLLOW 
               ON IFOLLOW.user_id = :userid AND IFOLLOW.following_id = U.id 
        LEFT JOIN follow_requests AS FR 
               ON FR.requester = :userid AND FR.user_id = U.id WHERE P.id = :postid";
```

I use `COUNT()` to count if the user is following/requested to follow the one who is viewing the likers list. If it says 1 it means they follow/requested them if 0 not. The problem is when I include the count methods it returns it as one result. When I don't include the count it returns multiple so I can run `foreach` through all them.

Am I doing something wrong to make it all as one result?

Comment: Append `GROUP BY U.id, U.name, U.username, U.verified, U.private` at the end of the query. See [GROUP BY clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `GROUP BY` clause if you want to aggregate over partitions and not over the whole tables. Try adding

```
GROUP BY U.id, U.name, U.username, U.verified, U.private
```

at the end of your query.